# Return Value Optimization and const getters for data members

Tags: c++, c++11, return-value-optimization

I understand that RVO enables copy elision of, amongst others, temporaries and local variables, but what about data members ?

To focus the question, which of the following three options is the best way to write a const getter for a data member (given RVO and C++11)?

```
class Widget { /* some large user-defined class */ };

class C
{
public:
    const Widget& getWidget1() const { return w; }
    const Widget getWidget2() const { return w; }
    Widget getWidget3() const { return w; }

private:
    Widget w;
};
```

Comment: Use `const Widget& getWidget1() const { return w; }`. I can see many situations where a copy will be problematic.

Comment: `const Widget getWidget2() const` is bad, the `const` in front of the return value inhibits move semantics

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ what about lifetimes issues with `C{}.getWidget1()`?

Comment: @TemplateRex Fair point. Depends on the actual use case though.

Comment: `const Widget& getWidget() const { return w; }` but `Widget takeWidget() { return std::move(w); }`

Comment: @Jarod42 or use ref-qualifiers: `const Widget& getWidget() const &`